# Nonlinear Regression with ODEs: Hypothesis Testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, modeling

I have curvefitted a differential equation model to a data set. The model itself has the equation $$\frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{\mathrm{d}t} = \alpha(1-Q^2) - \gamma\frac{Q}{4}$$ Again, I have values for $\alpha$ and $\gamma$. They are $0.09$ and $0.45$ respectively. I wish to do a hypothesis test on these parameters. Do I do this the same way as a linear regression hypothesis test. In other words, do I use the test statistic of $$t^* = \frac{\hat{\beta_1} - 0}{\text{SE}\left(\hat{\beta_1}\right)}$$ and do a simple t-test with $\text{df} = n-2$? Or is it more complicated than that? Can I use the same methods for calculating the standard error here as in normal, linear regression? Note that I am just using OLS as my cost function here.

Edit for comment: This is a model for a certain protein in the body. The model seeks to describe the way a protein reacts to a medicine. We have ample amounts of data. To curvefit, we simply found parameter values that resulted in the lowest SSE.

Comment: Please describe your data and your "curve fitting procedure," because the answer likely depends on those details.

Comment: Thank you, but it lacks sufficient detail.  How, in particular, did you estimate $dQ/dt$ and what exactly is the "SSE"?  For instance, one might view this as a multivariate regression in which the response is $(Q, dQ/dt)$ and therefore would normalize it in some way, perhaps account for covariances, and measure the quality of fit on a bivariate "SSE."  How did you sample the system--at equally spaced intervals of $t$, randomly, or some other way?  What assumptions do you make about errors in measuring $Q$ (or even $dQ/dt$ if you measure that directly)?